# Data macros in Access2010: triggers?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've heard on the grapevine that the forthcoming Access2010 has a Data Macros feature which will for the first time add trigger-like functionality to Access data engine tables. Does anybody have an further details on this? For example, can they created in code (ACEDAO, SQL DDL, etc)? Does the Data Macro run if the data is modified from outside of the Access user interface e.g. via ODBC, OLE DB, etc?

Comment: Likely anyone who knows the answer is under NDA and can't confirm this.

Comment: David, the NDA is being relaxed in some areas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, a bit more information.

> Does the Data Macro run if the data is modified from outside of the Access user interface e.g. via ODBC, OLE DB, etc?

Yes it does.

These true triggers are at the data engine level. So, using ado, dao or even editing the tables in table view in ms-access means the triggers will fire. These triggers would also include the scenario where you don’t even have ms-access installed on your computer.

You will of course need JET installed (for the remainder of this article I will use the term ACE). Remember it was only in access 2007 that the access team received ownership of JET. They are now free to enhance this engine for their needs. We started to see some changes to ACE in 2007 and now we will see a LOT more changes for 2010. Some of these features are still NDA for me…but I will spill as much as I can here.

> For example, can they created in code (ACEDAO, SQL DDL, etc)?

In code, perahps, but not with SQL ddl. The triggers are not sql commands. Keep in mind that for Oracle, or  Sql server or MOST systems in the marketplace they all tend to have their OWN custom language for their triggers anyway.

In the new ACE you thus will write what is called a data macro.  You use the macro editor in ms-access. These are old fashioned access macros, but the editor has been completely re-done. The new macros also have subroutines, looping, if then else blocks and a type of recordset. Remember, we received the ability to create temp variables in 2007 macros. In 2010 this is extended to also include local variables and above new features.

The syntax for existing macro commands is the same as previous versions. However, we have a new slick IDE along with all those above cool commands added. We now thus have two types of macros. UI macros (regular as before) and now the new so called data macros. It would not make sense for a table level macro to be able to display error messages to the screen. So any error logged goes into a table. There also a few new logging commands that let you write your own custom errors to that table . A brilliant and simple design here. Here what that error log table looks like:

[image]
<sub>(source: [kallal.ca](http://www.kallal.ca/test/merrors.png))</sub>

In a world of huge IDE’s, massive frame works and horrifying huge libraries of code requited to update a simple row in a table, I can say that data macros are most refreshing feature. They feel much like how the original dbaseII works. They are very simple, but deadly power full because they run at the table level.

For example, here is a data macro that will maintain inventorying totals a table. In this example I’m going to assume that master inventory  records exist. And then we have an order details table. If a user edits any value in the orders table, we want the master table to automatic update the inventory levels.

So we have:
I have two tables

```
tblFruits:    main data fruit inventory table
id         (autonumber)
Fruit text
OnHand    (number value of fruit in inventory)

tblFruitsOrder
id       (autonumber)
Fruit_id (FK to tblFruts.ID)
QtyOrder (number of fruit to order)
```

This is simple test

So, we going to have a trigger in the tblFruitsOrder that will update
+ maintain inventory levels in tblFruits when the QtyOrder field is
edited or modified.

Here is what the macro looks like:

[image]
<sub>(source: [kallal.ca](http://www.kallal.ca/test/macro1.png))</sub>

Note how very simple the above is.  Note that in the IDE if you click on a section of the code, then you get the old style macro type editing in which you can enter the values for the command (this is similar to pre 2010, but now the parameters and editing occurs in the code, not a panel that appears on the bottom of the screen in previous versions).

Here is another screen shot in which I playing with the ability to do a loop and call a subroutine.

[image]
<sub>(source: [kallal.ca](http://www.kallal.ca/test/macro22.png))</sub>

In the above we can use msgboxs etc. because this is not a table level macro. So the commands available are automatically restricted for you when you writing  a table level macro as opposed to a regular macro. The terminology we adopted to distinguish the two types of macros are UI macros and data macros.

The above is about all I can speak about in pubic. However there is few more REALLY neat-o features about these macros that I simply can not yet talk about in public as I am still under NDA on those features. But there is more cool surprises to come here.

Here is a screen shot of the types of table triggers we have:

[image]
<sub>(source: [kallal.ca](http://www.kallal.ca/test/macro3.png))</sub>

Comment: Wow, thanks Albert. Great detail as usual. Exciting stuff! :)

Comment: Something perhaps to test: you say they are table level but when are they checked: at the row level, the SQL statement level or the transaction level? One of the complaints I have about Jet 4.0 CHECK constraints is that, although they are table-level, they get checked at the row level. Consider a somewhat daft CHECK that tests that the table can only have exactly five rows. It is not checked when the table is empty obviously. Then you run an INSERT INTO..SELECT TOP 5.. style SQL statement to INSERT exactly 5 rows all at once...

Comment: ...HOWEVER the CHECK fires when the first row is created, obviously at this point there isn't five rows in the table, so the CHECK bites and the INSERT fails. This demonstrates that CHECK constraints are tested at the row level when they really should be tested at the SQL statement level at least, ideally at the transaction level (I'm thinking here of SQL-92's DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED as seen in Oracle); as it is, there is enough loss of utility to consider this a bug, IMO. A Data Macro that similarly fired for each row of a bulk INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE could be a pain.

Comment: These triggers will not change behavior of the check constraint (unfortantly). If the constraint does not allow the update then the trigger will not fire. You could create a table level validation macro but that’s not sql anymore. These new data macros don’t care nor know about those other issues. Anything that prevents a update means that the data macro will not fire. Validation macros or RI, or check constraints means No update = no trigger. Wrapping the above in a transaction would also not change anything here since all tables updated always rolled back if you bail out of the transaction.

Comment: Good point about the sequence of events (i.e. CHECK before Data Macro) but what I meant was the timing of the firing of the Data Macro when, for example, INSERTing five rows all at once using a INSERT INTO..SELECT TOP 5.. construct (or similar). Does the Data Macro fire five times i.e. once for each new row? This is what happens for a CHECK constraint which is a problem/bug. I'm not in a position to critique Data Macros (but all sounds good from here), just something you could test so any potential problem could fixed if identified early. Thanks.

Comment: The trigger would fire 5 times. You could perhaps write a table validation macro which would also fire each time and it could stop things from inserting after 5 records.  However this is not sql anymore. You writing code so it seems that wrapping this in a transaction and checking at the end of the code to commit is the best workaround I can suggest. 

Keep in mind that ACE is not really a true atomic data engine and I don’t think it ever will be. At least now we can make suggestions to the access team where as before it was a deaf ears type of thing. I put this in my list of suggestions.

Comment: Firing five times is not so good but was what I was expecting to be honest: I've long suspected there is something at the engine level that can't 'see' beyond the row level (the same is still true of SQL Server from what I can tell). Thanks for raising it as a suggestion though. As you say, at least the Access team are listening. I note that in ACE they fixed the DECIMAL sort bug (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837148) which surprised and impressed me. Thanks again.

Comment: The list of events pretty much demonstrates that it fires at the row level, don't you think?

Comment: @David W. Fenton: yes, I think you are correct but I think the firing at the row level is less useful than firing at the statement level.

Comment: @onedaywhen: A file-based database could probably never handle that. You'd need a "traffic cop" serializing the updates in order to avoid major problems with locks from multiple users triggering such events at the table level simultaneously (or close enough to overlap). This feature is excellent feature, and the way they've implemented it has much in common with form events, which are by definition record-based. There's a certain consistency there, and it means a lot of things that previously had to be done in form events can now be done by the db engine, and be accessible by non-Access apps.

Comment: @David W. Fenton: "accessible by non-Access apps" -- but you need Access to create/update/delete the Macro, right? I want to write my database code in SQL of course ;)

Comment: @David W. Fenton: "This feature is excellent feature, and the way they've implemented it has much in common with form events, which are by definition record-based" -- but not a great fit with SQL code which is statement-based and can obviously involve multiple rows. Are we finally at the point where the Access database engine is only fit for Access Forms applications?

Comment: @David W. Fenton: "A file-based database could probably never handle that. You'd need a "traffic cop" serializing the updates" -- you could be correct. I guess a 'server' database will always be the correct solution for me :) This could be where I part company with the Access database engine...

Answer (score 1):

More information on this new feature was [posted today](http://blogs.msdn.com/access/archive/2009/08/13/access-2010-data-macros-similar-to-triggers.aspx) on the MS Access development team's blog and it definitely provides more information on the crucial question raised in the comments above.