# How to set Constraint on date field?

Tags: sql, datetime, ms-access

I have `release_date` as date datatype field in a table in MS Access.

How can I ensure all dates inserted in this field are after some constant date like '01-01-2015'?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

### JET

*You can't.*

MS Access (JET and ACE) does not support `CHECK` constraints - [only `FOREIGN KEY` and `UNIQUE` constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/constraint-clause-microsoft-access-sql).

### ACE

If you're using ACE (Access 2007+ `.accdb` files only) then you can use a [an "Before Change" data-macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/before-change-macro-event).

Note that data-macros are distinct from "normal" Access macros: they're more lightweight but they [do work when when used from other applications via ODBC and OLE-DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159394/data-macros-in-access2010-triggers) whereas "normal" macros only work from within the Access environment.

Answer (score 0):

With your table in Design View, select the Validation Rule for your `release_date` field and enter `> #01-01-2015#`

If you want to implement it with a check constraint, execute the DDL statement with OleDb.

```vb
strDDL = "ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name" & vbCrLF & _
    "CHECK (release_date > #2015-01-01#)"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strDDL
```

That works because `CurrentProject.Connection` uses an OleDb provider.  But I think setting the Validation Rule property is the simpler solution.